# Why does value restriction happen with MergeSort function?

Tags: f#, mergesort, value-restriction

I have a very simple [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) implementation on List.

```
/// Divide the list into (almost) equal halves
let rec split = function
    | [] -> [], []
    | [x] -> [x], []
    | x1::x2::xs -> let xs1, xs2 = split xs
                    x1::xs1, x2::xs2

/// Merge two sorted lists
let rec merge xs ys =
    match xs, ys with
    | [], _ -> ys
    | _, [] -> xs
    | x::xs', y::ys' when x <= y -> x::merge xs' ys
    | _, y::ys' -> y::merge xs ys' 

let rec mergeSort = function
    | [] -> []
    | xs -> let xs1, xs2 = split xs
            merge (mergeSort xs1) (mergeSort xs2)
```

But whenever I tried to test with any input in F# Interactive:

```
let xs = mergeSort [1;4;3;2];;
```

I encountered a value restriction error:

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'xs' has been inferred to
>   have generic type
>       val xs : '_a list when '_a : comparison     Either define 'xs' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if
>   you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

*Why does it happen? What is a simple way to fix it?*

Comment: see [Finer Points of F# Value Restriction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx)

Comment: When I paste the code into `FSI` I get no error messages on `F# 2.0 Interactive build 2.0.0.0`

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Of course not. Try to execute the function on some input.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella: Thanks, I'm aware of the article. I'm just puzzled why it did happen in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not handling the special case of 1-element lists in `mergeSort`.
The general case is "too general" to infer the right type. As a consequence, the compiler infers a too generic type for the function ('a list -> 'b list) and the result is always a generic list (which is not allowed due to value restriction).

If you fix it like this, the type will be correctly inferred as 'a list -> 'a list.

```
let rec mergeSort = function
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [x]
    | xs -> let xs1, xs2 = split xs
            merge (mergeSort xs1) (mergeSort xs2)
```

Comment: This also explains crashes for odd input lengths in the original code